# google maps is not loading in properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have been working on this website http://www.knudtzon.co and I have tried to include a google maps in the contact page. Unfortunately, the maps doesn't render properly, and when I navigate in the maps, it still doesn't work or load in content properly. I have found out that if I re do my script, so that the google maps is the first thing appearing on the screen, the map actually loads in correctly, but that doesn't really suit my design-wishes that much :)

I have looked for solutions on this, and tried to reload the map when I open the contact page, but it still doesn't seem to work. My log doesn't show any errors or anything, so I can't seem to figure it out.

If anybody has an idea of how to solve this, it would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, once you are done with displaying the contact div, you need to call the `resize` event on google map.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(selector, mapOptions); //Initialising map.
var currCenter = map.getCenter(); //Get the center location of the map
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //Trigger resize
map.setCenter(currCenter); //Setting the center in resized map.
```

Should be easy. Make sure you call this code after your `contact div` is loaded/resized/animated completely.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: The concept you wrote is correct and also the procedure I previously tried to use. I figured that I had to use the code differently. Thanks.

Comment: I had same issue once and tried this way, it worked for me. Hope it works for you too.